# What's stored in that Tcl variable?

Tags: tcl

Pursuant to the advice given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385156/how-do-i-retrofit-a-gui-to-an-existing-c-program) I have written a little gui to take the options for a command line C program and pass them on to said C program which is already set up to process them. It displays just like I wanted.

However, I would like to verify that the values stored in the variables are correct.  **Getting the values to print out is giving me a lot of grief** (I can't test *in vivo* right now due to some hardware issues). What am I missing?

1. Prepending the variable name with '$' gives me '$variableName' rather than the *value* of the variable.
2. Adding these variables to an array and calling `array get arr` is supposed to print the index and the array value; I get variable names.
3. I tried *pathName* `cget` *option*, but apparently `-value` isn't an option, and leaving off the option doesn't give me a list of valid options.

Here's all the code with the various things that didn't work (from option #1, which is the most straightforward way; the others were just me trying workarounds). They all produce
errors along the lines of: "can't read "::": no such variable" or "can't read
"colorimetric": no such variable".

```
#!/opt/ActiveTcl-8.5/bin/wish8.5

wm title . "Gretag"

ttk::frame .f -borderwidth 5 -relief sunken -padding "5 10"

# next line part of the "puts" tests at the bottom
global colorimetric
ttk::label .f.dataLabel -text "Data Type"
ttk::label .f.colorimetricLabel -text "Colorimetric"
ttk::checkbutton .f.colorimetric -onvalue "-c" -offvalue "" -command getFilename1
ttk::label .f.spectralLabel -text "Spectral"
ttk::checkbutton .f.spectral -onvalue "-s" -offvalue "" -command getFilename2 

ttk::label .f.gretagNumLabel -text "Gretag #"
ttk::label .f.gretagLabel0 -text "1"
ttk::radiobutton .f.gretagRadio0 -variable gretagNum -value "/dev/ttyS0" 
ttk::label .f.gretagLabel1 -text "2"
ttk::radiobutton .f.gretagRadio1 -variable gretagNum -value "/dev/ttyS1"
ttk::label .f.gretagLabel2 -text "3"
ttk::radiobutton .f.gretagRadio2 -variable gretagNum -value "/dev/ttyS2" 
ttk::label .f.gretagLabel3 -text "4"
ttk::radiobutton .f.gretagRadio3 -variable gretagNum -value "/dev/ttyS3" 
ttk::label .f.gretagLabel4 -text "5"
ttk::radiobutton .f.gretagRadio4 -variable gretagNum -value "/dev/ttyS4" 

ttk::label .f.sampleSize -text "Sample Size"
ttk::label .f.samplex -text "X"
ttk::label .f.sampley -text "Y"
ttk::entry .f.x -textvariable x -width 5 
ttk::entry .f.y -textvariable y -width 5 

ttk::label .f.filterLabel -text "Filter Type"
ttk::label .f.filterLabel0 -text "D50"
ttk::radiobutton .f.filterRadio0 -variable filter -value "-d50" 
ttk::label .f.filterLabel1 -text "D65"
ttk::radiobutton .f.filterRadio1 -variable filter -value "-d65" 
ttk::label .f.filterLabel2 -text "Unfiltered"
ttk::radiobutton .f.filterRadio2 -variable filter -value "-U" 
ttk::label .f.filterLabel3 -text "Polarized"
ttk::radiobutton .f.filterRadio3 -variable filter -value "-p" 

ttk::label .f.baudLabel -text "Baud Rate"
ttk::label .f.baudLabel0 -text "4800"
ttk::radiobutton .f.baudRadio0 -variable baud -value "B4800" 
ttk::label .f.baudLabel1 -text "9600"
ttk::radiobutton .f.baudRadio1 -variable baud -value "B9600" 
ttk::label .f.baudLabel2 -text "19200"
ttk::radiobutton .f.baudRadio2 -variable baud -value "B19200" 
ttk::label .f.baudLabel3 -text "38400"
ttk::radiobutton .f.baudRadio3 -variable baud -value "B38400" 
ttk::label .f.baudLabel4 -text "57600"
ttk::radiobutton .f.baudRadio4 -variable baud -value "B57600" 

ttk::button .f.submitBtn -text "Submit" -command finish

grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1
grid rowconfigure . 0 -weight 1
grid .f -column 0 -row 0 -columnspan 11 -rowspan 5

grid .f.dataLabel -column 0 -row 0 -sticky we
grid .f.colorimetricLabel -column 1 -row 0 -sticky e
grid .f.colorimetric -column 2 -row 0 -sticky w
grid .f.spectralLabel -column 3 -row 0 -sticky e
grid .f.spectral -column 4 -row 0 -sticky w

grid .f.gretagNumLabel -column 0 -row 1 -sticky we
grid .f.gretagLabel0 -column 1 -row 1 -sticky e
grid .f.gretagRadio0 -column 2 -row 1 -sticky w
grid .f.gretagLabel1 -column 3 -row 1 -sticky e
grid .f.gretagRadio1 -column 4 -row 1 -sticky w
grid .f.gretagLabel2 -column 5 -row 1 -sticky e
grid .f.gretagRadio2 -column 6 -row 1 -sticky w
grid .f.gretagLabel3 -column 7 -row 1 -sticky e
grid .f.gretagRadio3 -column 8 -row 1 -sticky w
grid .f.gretagLabel4 -column 9 -row 1 -sticky e
grid .f.gretagRadio4 -column 10 -row 1 -sticky w

grid .f.sampleSize -column 0 -row 2 -sticky we
grid .f.samplex -column 1 -row 2 -sticky e
grid .f.x -column 2 -row 2 -sticky w
grid .f.sampley -column 3 -row 2 -sticky e
grid .f.y -column 4 -row 2 -sticky w

grid .f.filterLabel -column 0 -row 3 -sticky we
grid .f.filterLabel0 -column 1 -row 3 -sticky e
grid .f.filterRadio0 -column 2 -row 3 -sticky w
grid .f.filterLabel1 -column 3 -row 3 -sticky e
grid .f.filterRadio1 -column 4 -row 3 -sticky w
grid .f.filterLabel2 -column 5 -row 3 -sticky e
grid .f.filterRadio2 -column 6 -row 3 -sticky w
grid .f.filterLabel3 -column 7 -row 3 -sticky e
grid .f.filterRadio3 -column 8 -row 3 -sticky w

grid .f.baudLabel -column 0 -row 4 -sticky we
grid .f.baudLabel0 -column 1 -row 4 -sticky e
grid .f.baudRadio0 -column 2 -row 4 -sticky w
grid .f.baudLabel1 -column 3 -row 4 -sticky e
grid .f.baudRadio1 -column 4 -row 4 -sticky w
grid .f.baudLabel2 -column 5 -row 4 -sticky e
grid .f.baudRadio2 -column 6 -row 4 -sticky w
grid .f.baudLabel3 -column 7 -row 4 -sticky e
grid .f.baudRadio3 -column 8 -row 4 -sticky w
grid .f.baudLabel4 -column 9 -row 4 -sticky e
grid .f.baudRadio4 -column 10 -row 4 -sticky w

grid .f.submitBtn -column 1 -row 5 -columnspan 7 -sticky we

foreach w [winfo children .f] {grid configure $w -padx 5 -pady 5}
focus .f.colorimetric
.f.colorimetric state selected
.f.filterRadio1 state selected
.f.baudRadio1 state selected
bind . <Return> {finish}

proc getFilename1 {} {
set filename1 [tk_getSaveFile]
}

proc getFilename2 {} {
set filename2 [tk_getSaveFile]
}

proc finish {} {
.f.x insert 0 "-x"
.f.y insert 0 "-y"
# Pick one
# puts $colorimetric
# puts colorimetric
# puts "$colorimetric"
# puts $::colorimetric
# puts .f.colorimetric
# puts $.f.colorimetric
# puts $::.f.colorimetric
# puts "$::colorimetric"
exec ./gretag .f.colorimetric filename1 .f.spectral filename2 .f.gretagNum .f.x .f.y .f.filter .f.baud
}
```

---

**Edit:** 
I've posted all the code rather than just part, and in the next to last line are the various syntaxes from option #1 that I've tried in order to view the values of the variables before they're passed to the next program. None of these are working and I don't understand why or how to fix it. I'm hoping another set of eyes will catch what's wrong.

Comment: BTW, learn to use the packer.  It's by far the most useful of the Tk layout managers.

Comment: Could you show in your question the exact syntax that does not work, in context?

Comment: @NXC: from the TkDocs tutorial (http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html): "Grid has all the power of pack, generally produces nicer layouts , ... and is easier to learn and use. Because of that, we think grid is the right choice for most developers most of the time. " I'm all about easier.

Comment: @Arkadiy: I'm going to put up the entire script instead of just part, with the things that didn't work.

Comment: I've never heard someone say pack was more useful than grid. I've been using pack for well over a decade and can do it in my sleep, but even I wouldn't consider it more useful. More useful in some circumstances, less in others. 

Use the right tool for the job, and in this case with the look the OP was trying to achieve grid is absolutely the right tool for the job.

Comment: Note that you can use a one-liner to pack a widget: `grid [ttk::button .baz -text "Foo Bar" -command bar] -column 1 -row 2 -sticky news`. If you adhere to the 80-column theory, though, be ready to include backslashes.

Answer (score 5):

### Variable Basics

As others have pointed out, the confusing **to $ or not to $** notation can be simplified by the following rule.

> **var** is a reference to the variable itself, not its value
>
> **$var** yields the value held in the variable

It can become a little more confusing when you start to think of everything in Tcl as a string (it's really not, but close enough), so you can store the name of one variable in another and restore its value by reference.

```
% set foo "hi"
hi
% set bar "foo"
foo
% set $foo
can't read "hi": no such variable
% set $bar
hi
```

Here the notation `set $foo` is evaluated in step - first `$foo` yields its value `hi` and then the `set` expression (when run with no third argument) attempts to return the value held in the variable `hi`. This fails. The notation `set $bar` takes the same steps but this time `set` can operate on the value of `bar`, which is `foo`, and thus returns the value of `foo` which is `hi`. [(link to "set" API)](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/set.htm)

### Initialization

One problem you have in this script is initialization. In Tcl variables don't exist until they're assigned a value. That's clearly why trying to `set $foo` above didn't work, because there was no variable `hi`.

At the top of your script you attempt to declare a variable with,

```
global colorimetric
```

which doesn't work, because you are already operating in global scope. Global "has no effect unless executed in the context of a proc body." [(link to "global" API)](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/global.htm) You actually have to use a `set` command to initialize the variable. This is why none of your attempts to print `colorimetric` in `proc finish` worked.

### Scope

The other problem you have in this script is scope, particularly with mixing global and procedural/local scope. You're correct that, had you initialized `colorimetric` correctly then the code,

```
puts $::colorimetric ;# print the value of the global variable colorimetric
```

would have worked. Another way to achieve this is with,

```
global colorimetric ;# reference a global variable into the local scope
puts $colorimetric  ;# print the value of colorimetric in the local scope
```

### My Solution

I'd like to present my solution. I admit that I've moved a lot of code around, and I will go into a short explanation of what changes I implemented to make it more concise.

```
#!/usr/bin/env wish

# --- default configuration --- #
array set CONF {
    colorimetric "-c"
    spectral     ""
    cfilename    "/path/to/defaultCI.txt"
    sfilename    ""
    x            0
    y            0
    gretagnum    "/dev/ttyS0"
    filter       "-d65"
    baud         "B9600"
}

# --- build the interface --- #
wm title . "Gretag"
ttk::frame .f -borderwidth 5 -relief sunken -padding "5 10"
grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1
grid rowconfigure    . 0 -weight 1
grid .f


ttk::label .f.dataLabel -text "Data Type: "
foreach {dtname dttag dtfile} {
    colorimetric "-c" cfilename
    spectral     "-s" sfilename
} {
    lappend mygrid [
        ttk::checkbutton .f.$dtname -text [string totitle $dtname] \
        -variable CONF($dtname) -onvalue $dttag -offvalue "" \
        -command [list getFilename $dtname $dttag $dtfile ]
    ]
}
grid .f.dataLabel {*}$mygrid -sticky w ; set mygrid { }


ttk::label .f.gretagNumLabel -text "Gretag #: "
for {set tty 0} {$tty < 5} {incr tty} {
    lappend mygrid [
        ttk::radiobutton .f.gretagRadio$tty -text [expr $tty + 1] \
        -variable CONF(gretagnum) -value "/dev/ttyS$tty" 
    ]
}
grid .f.gretagNumLabel {*}$mygrid -sticky w ; set mygrid { }


ttk::label .f.sampleSize -text "Sample Size: "
ttk::label .f.samplex -text "X"
ttk::label .f.sampley -text "Y"
ttk::entry .f.x -textvariable CONF(x) -width 5 
ttk::entry .f.y -textvariable CONF(x) -width 5 
grid .f.sampleSize .f.samplex .f.x .f.sampley .f.y


ttk::label .f.filterLabel -text "Filter Type: "
foreach {ftname ftval} {
    D50        "-d50"
    D65        "-d65"
    Unfiltered "-U"
    Polarized  "-P"
} {
    lappend mygrid [
        ttk::radiobutton .f.filterRadio$ftname -text $ftname \
        -variable CONF(filter) -value $ftval
    ]
}
grid .f.filterLabel {*}$mygrid -sticky w ; set mygrid { }


ttk::label .f.baudLabel -text "Baud Rate: "
foreach {baud} {
    4800 9600 19200 38400 57600
} {
    lappend mygrid [
        ttk::radiobutton .f.baudRadio$baud -text $baud \
        -variable CONF(baud) -value "B$baud"
    ]
}
grid .f.baudLabel {*}$mygrid -sticky w ; set mygrid { }


ttk::button .f.submitBtn -text "Submit" -command submit
grid .f.submitBtn -columnspan 6 -sticky we

foreach w [winfo children .f] {
    grid configure $w -padx 5 -pady 5
}
focus .f.colorimetric
bind . <Return> submit

# --- callbacks --- #
proc getFilename {type tag file} {
    global CONF

    if {$CONF($type) eq $tag} {
        set CONF($file) [tk_getOpenFile]
        if {$CONF($file) eq ""} { .f.$type invoke }
    } else {
        set CONF($file) ""
    }
}

proc submit { } {
    global CONF

    exec ./gretag $CONF(colorimetric) $CONF(cfilename) \
        $CONF(spectral) $CONF(sfilename) $CONF(gretagnum) \
        $CONF(x) $CONF(y) $CONF(filter) $CONF(baud)
}
```

### Discussion of Changes

**1.** The first changes I made were to use the `-text` options on the `ttk::checkbutton` and `ttk::radiobutton`. Granted, using an extra label for these allows you to place the text before the button, but doing so is non-standard and requires more code.

```
ttk::label .f.colorimetricLabel -text "Colorimetric"
ttk::checkbutton .f.colorimetric -onvalue "-c" -offvalue "" -command getFilename1
```

becomes

```
ttk::checkbutton .f.colorimetric -text "Colorimetric" -onvalue "-c" -offvalue "" -command getFilename1
```

---

**2.** Next I used the similarities between these two checkbuttons to abstract the creation into a foreach. (I do this all the time in my Tcl code for work.) This generates much easier code to read and allows you to add/remove/swap names and tags for the widgets. It results in slightly more but much more versitile code.

```
ttk::checkbutton .f.colorimetric -text "Colorimetric" -onvalue "-c" -offvalue "" -command getFilename1
ttk::checkbutton .f.colorimetric -text "Spectral" -onvalue "-s" -offvalue "" -command getFilename2
```

becomes

```
foreach {dtname dttag dtcommand} {
    colorimetric "-c" getFilename1
    spectral     "-s" getFilename2
} {
        ttk::checkbutton .f.$dtname -text [string totitle $dtname] -onvalue $dttag -offvalue "" -command $dtcommand
}
```

---

**3.** The next change was to merge your `getFilename1` and `getFilename2` into a single `getFilename` procedure. We can pass arguments into this function to determine who is calling it. I use the `list` command to generate the call for this new function. [(link to "list" API)](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/list.htm)

I also started to combine your `grid` commands into the widget code itself. Here `mygrid` keeps a list of what needs to be gridded per line in the GUI and then is evaluated at the end of each section to propagate the GUI on the fly. [(link to "grid" API)](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/grid.htm)

The previous code gets its final revision and becomes,

```
foreach {dtname dttag dtfile} {
    colorimetric "-c" cfilename
    spectral     "-s" sfilename
} {
    lappend mygrid [
        ttk::checkbutton .f.$dtname -text [string totitle $dtname] -variable CONF($dtname) -onvalue $dttag -offvalue "" -command [list getFilename $dtname $dttag $dtfile ]
    ]
}
```

Then the `grid` command can be evaluated and the `mygrid` variable cleared after every use!

---

**4.** If you've been paying attention I also added a `-variable` option to your `ttk::checkbutton` and at this point started storing the button state in a global variable `CONF`. This is a big change.

Tk loves to pollute your global namespace and it's good practice to fight back. I usually put all of my configuration state in a global array, and set that right up top of the code so that anyone can come in and change the default state of my code, without digging into it or doing search/replace calls or anything like that. Just good practice, so wherever you had a variable I moved it into `CONF` and moved `CONF` up top.

```
array set CONF {
    colorimetric "-c"
    spectral     ""
    cfilename    "/path/to/defaultCI.txt"
    sfilename    ""
    x            0
    y            0
    gretagnum    "/dev/ttyS0"
    filter       "-d65"
    baud         "B9600"
}
```

---

**5.** Next I propagated these changes throughout your code. Almost all of the widget creation was susceptible to these revisions. With respect to the widget creation this sometimes made independent code sections larger. But it also allowed me to remove your entire grid section, merging this code up into the widget code as I've discussed, greatly decreasing the size and clutter of your code at the added expense of complexity.

---

**6.** The final changes I made were to your function code. You have a couple of minor bugs in your `getFilename1` and `getFilename2` code. The first bug was that you want to call `tk_getOpenFile` because I gather you are only grabbing an existing file name to pass it to `gretag`. [(link to 'tk_getOpenFile' API)](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/getOpenFile.htm) If you use `tk_getOpenFile` the dialog will make sure the file exists.

The second bug in `getFilename1` is that the dialog has a `Cancel` button, and if the user clicks this cancel button the dialog returns an empty string. In this case you have to un-check the `ttk::checkbutton` and you have to unset the `CONF(colorimetric)` variable. Or more correctly you have to set `CONF(colorimetric)` to the button's `-offvalue`. You can do both of these at once by sending a click event to the current button.

```
proc getFilename1 {} {
set filename1 [tk_getSaveFile]
}
```

becomes

```
proc getFilename {type tag file} {
    global CONF

    if {$CONF($type) eq $tag} {
        set CONF($file) [tk_getOpenFile]
        if {$CONF($file) eq ""} { .f.$type invoke }
    } else {
        set CONF($file) ""
    }
}
```

In your `finish` function I renamed the function to `submit` (sorry) and rewrote it to make use of the new `CONF` variable.

### The Answer

Of course most of this was unnecessary. I wanted to give you some interesting Tcl/Tk code to think about while at the same time solving your problem. At this point we should have the vocabulary to answer your question, though.

The reason your variables weren't printing out was because of initialization and scope. You should always use a `-variable` or `-textvariable` on widgets that you need to reference later. I generally initialize my referenced variables before building their containing widgets. So at the top of your file if you had done,

```
set colorimetric "-c"
ttk::checkbutton .f.colorimetric -variable colorimetric [...]
```

Then you would have been able to do, in the `finish` function,

```
puts $::colorimetric
```

Comment: The choice of using an array is a good one. It's a very effective technique for keeping all the values for a form (dialog, property sheet, whatever you want to call it) together. 

However, from a style perspective I think I like the OP better. I understand your rationale but I think the original reads better. It's easier to see where the widgets are created and how they are laid out.

Comment: You may have a good point there about the OP readability of widgets and layout. I didn't initially want to revise the grid section but when I switched to dynamic widget naming that started to feel dangerous, and I figured I'd better just automate it all.

Answer (score 2):

You have not assigned any variable to the colorimetric checkbutton.
Add -variable colorimetric to the checkbutton, and then in finish
you can use:
puts $::colorimetric

Also, set ::colorimetric first to select your default value. That
is easier than trying to mess with the state of the widget.

I see that the values colorimetric can have are "" and "-c" so
I assume you will use that value in the exec line.
Beware that [exec something yada $::colorimetric something] will
probably not work then. You'll probably need {*}$::colorimetric in the
exec line to make the argument disappear if it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little tcl snippet - run from tclsh or wish

```
[nigel@rose ~]$ wish
% set foo /dev/ttys0
/dev/ttys0
% puts $foo
/dev/ttys0
% puts "$foo"
/dev/ttys0
% puts [$foo]
invalid command name "/dev/ttys0"
% puts ($foo)
(/dev/ttys0)
% puts {$foo}
$foo
%
```

Quoting in Tcl:

- `""` (double quotes): Evaluate substitutions ($variable)
- `{}` {Squiggly brackets): Treat the entire string as a literal with no substitution
- `[]` (Square brackets): Execute the string as a command with substitution

As an alternative you could pop up the diagnostic in a dialog box:

```
% set mb [tk_messageBox -message "Port is $foo" -type ok -icon info]
ok
%
```

Comment: It has to work in a script, not just from the Tcl command line. I think that's why I'm having trouble finding the right syntax.

Comment: kajaco, your comment doesn't seem to address the real problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

At your "# Just here" comment, try adding

puts $::gretagNum

:: signifies a global variable, and the -variable option to widgets
are always global.

Comment: or adding
    global gretagNum
should help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do, put if you end put printing the variable name and not the variable content, use the **set** command *as function*:

set content "hello"

set blah content

if you do:

```
puts $blah
```

.. you get the content of the blah variable, which is content.

To get the content of the variable content via blah, use the following:

```
puts [set $blah]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remember this rule and you will always get it right:

```
$foo is shorthand for [set foo]
```

Try rewriting your code with [set foo] and it will work.

In particular,

```
$$foo  ;# not what you think
```

is replaced by

```
[set [set foo]]   ;# does what you think
```

Comment: while you are technically correct, this does nothing to answer the actual question.