# What library is best for GUI in python?

Tags: python, user-interface

#### Duplicate:

> [Cross-platform gui toolkit for deploying Python applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520015/cross-platform-gui-toolkit-for-deploying-python-applications)

I want to create a GUI application in python. Which library is best one?

Comment: @Click Upvote: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593

Comment: Where does it say to remove salutation from a question?

Comment: Your link clearly indicates that you're in the wrong here, Can.

Comment: Obviously it's open to interpretation, but I remove all the Hi's and Thanks' when I see a signature.

Comment: the only authoritative say there is from Jeff, who says "If I am already editing a post for one of these reasons, I will generally go ahead and take out any greeting/salutation at the beginning. [...] I rarely remove a “Thanks” at the end unless it’s long and apologetic" your eidt was specifically

Comment: to remove those parts. I've no problem with you doing it, as long as you're not claiming that some common conscious of SO supports you.

Comment: @Silent Ghost: I'm not saying everyone agrees on this, and I don't *usually* edit posts only to remove salutations or signatures. On this question, however, the salutation and signature were 2 lines, where the question itself was only 1 line. That's fair game to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the question [Cross-platform gui toolkit for deploying Python applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520015/cross-platform-gui-toolkit-for-deploying-python-applications):

> ## [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro)
>
> It's build on top of [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/), a C++
>   framework. It's quite advanced and has
>   some good tools like the Qt Designer
>   to design your applications. You
>   should be aware though, that it
>   doesn't feel like Python 100%, but
>   close to it.
>
> This framework is really good. It's
>   being actively developed by Trolltech,
>   who is owned by Nokia. The bindings
>   for Python are developed by Riverbank.
>
> Nokia announced that they'd start to
>   use LGPL for the Qt-Framework starting
>   with Qt 4.5 (to be released in April,
>   I think), but it's not yet sure if
>   Riverbank follows this and releases
>   the bindings for Python under LGPL
>   too. (They have a commercial and a GPL
>   licence at the moment.)
>
> Qt is not only a GUI-framework but has
>   a lot of other classes too, one can
>   create an application by just using Qt
>   classes. (Like SQL, networking…)
>
> Qt doesn't use native GUI elements,
>   but wikipedia mentions that in recent
>   versions [Qt uses native
>   widgets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_toolkit#Use_of_native_UI-rendering_APIs) where
>   possible. I haven't found evidence in
>   [the documentation but for Mac OS
>   X](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.4/qtmac-as-native.html).
>
> ## [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/)
>
> wxPython is a binding for Python using
>   the [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)-Framework.
>   This framework is under the LGPL
>   licence and is developed by the open
>   source community.
>
> What I'm really missing is a good tool
>   to design the interface, they have
>   about 3 but none of them is usable.
>
> One thing I should mention is that I
>   found a bug in the tab-view despite
>   the fact that I didn't use anything
>   advanced. (Only on Mac OS X) I think
>   [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) isn't as
>   polished as [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/).
>
> wxPython is really only about the
>   GUI-classes, there isn't much else.
>
> wxWidgets uses native GUI elements.
>
> ## Others
>
> I haven't got any experience with
>   other GUI frameworks, maybe someone
>   else has.

Answer (score 5):

wxWidgets (the Python flavor is called [wxPython](http://wxpython.org)) is currently your best option IMHO, they have support for multi platform (Mac, Window, Linux) and the framework is pretty easy to work with.

[From the site](http://www.wxwidgets.org):

*wxWidgets lets developers create applications for Win32, Mac OS X, GTK+, X11, Motif, WinCE, and more  using one codebase. It can be used from languages such as C++, Python, Perl, and C#/.NET. Unlike other cross-platform toolkits, wxWidgets applications look and feel native. This is because wxWidgets uses the platform's own native controls rather than emulating them. It's also extensive, free, open-source, and mature. Why not give it a try, like*

Answer (score 3):

I like [PyQt](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt). wxPython has many warts, and the code you write in PyQt is often much cleaner. The UI designer is very helpful as well.

Comment: +1 as I personally also like PyQt more then wxPython

Answer (score 1):

For general-purpose GUI applications, I would recommend [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/).  It's the python flavor of the [wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org/) project.  It's easy to work with, cross-platform, full-featured and the demo is actually a great tutorial.

For game-like GUIs, I would go with [pyGame](http://www.pygame.org/).  It's also very simple and powerful: you can program a little game in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/).

Answer (score -1):

TKInter. easiest.

Comment: You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349409/why-are-tk-guis-considered-ugly for another opinion on that

Comment: Ugliest of course :-) but it was the first GUI i used in python, while i was learning it.